# What are the disadvantages of using ultra compression?

Tags: compression, archiving, 7-zip

[image: ultra compression]

7zip offers an option for ultra compression but I'm guessing that it has some disadvantages (other than being more time consuming) or else it would have been the default option... So what are they?

Comment: @cybernard - that should be an answer rather then a comment -I'd upvote it.

Comment: Note to close voters: I don't think this is primarily opinion-based; there are definitely facts to call on. I'm voting Leave Open.

Answer (score 2):

slower and more memory used. Many people are like I saved 1-5% and waited 5x longer, nope goodbye. This is not always the case, but some data doesn't compress more 1-5% better than normal.